# Why does James Bond burn the paper M gives him in 'You Only Live Twice'?

Tags: plot-explanation, james-bond, you-only-live-twice

In *You Only Live Twice* (1967) M hands a note to 007 containing the address and name of the target Bond's supposed to meet in Tokyo. Instead of telling him these details, they are written in a piece of paper and when 007 receives it, he immediately uses his lighter to burn it after taking a glimpse at it. Why? Is he following protocol or is this an exaggeration to secrecy for something that seems unnecessary here? I don't remember seeing this ever again in a Bond movie.

[image]

Comment: The information may also be written instead of spoken because it's perhaps easier to remember a visual image (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_learning)

Comment: @Longshanks It also could be done as an extra layer of precaution if there is a concern that the room is bugged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like a security protocol. He works for secret services, all the information he leaves behind can be a risk.

Self destruct messages, removing signs and burning paper message is a common trope in spy films.

Refer [This Page Will Self-Destruct](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThisPageWillSelfDestruct) trope for details.